# Let $X = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy,z)$. Compute $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $X = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy,z)$. Denote by $U$ the open subset obtained by deleting the closed point $\mathfrak{m}=(x,y,z)$. Compute $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.

I have understood that we can compute the local sections of the structure sheaf by considering the distinguished open sets $D(f)$ as we have that $$\mathcal{O}_X(D(f))= A[1/f]$$ for a ring $A$. In my case we can see that $$U = D(x) \cup D(y) \cup D(z)$$ right? We define $D(f)$ to be the set of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $f(\mathfrak{p}) \ne 0$ so $U$ is the set where neither of the functions $x,y$ or $z$ vanishes. Do we have some theorem for $\mathcal{O}_X$ over the union of $D(f)$'s? It would seem like I need one in this problem.

Comment: You need to describe what happens on the intersections of the distinguished open sets you’ve got. They you need to determine how to glue those sections to determine the $O(U)$. This is just because it is a sheaf.

Comment: I guess that $D(x) \cap D(y) \cap D(z) = D(xyz)$. What sections are you talking about here? @AHappyMathematician

Comment: The point I am trying to get at is that there is not generally a good way to compute $O(U)$ if $U$ is a union unless $U$ is a disjoint union. For example, look at $Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and try to compute $O(U)$ for $U:=D(x)\cup D(y)$. This is just the affine plane with the origin removed and you glue sections to show that $O(U)$ here is just $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.